# Active item not display in ckeditor toolbar (Drupal v9)

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

When i move item, everything oke:
[image]

But in view in disappear
[image]

i use Drupal 9.2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use all items option, you have to use "**FULL HTML**" format.

For example: *You are using "Basic HTML" format in your content type, then you can not use  element. If you want to add it, you have to be sure to select the correct format "FULL HTML".*

If you cant select this format check the permissions or field content type config.

Be carefull, give this permissions to a trusted role.